# Organize bars in ggplot2 with legend

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, bar-chart

Hello I am trying to order the bars in ggplot2.

This is the `New` dataframe:

```
  Mb       category       reason
585.79       All           Known 
170.55       All            New 
126.67    Overlapped        New 
252.29    Overlapped       Known 
10.95     Reciprocal        New 
37.89     Reciprocal       Known 
40.27      Absolute         New 
118.58     Absolute        Known
```

This is the plot script:

`ggplot(New, aes(factor(reason), Mb, fill = category)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity" , position = "dodge") + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1") + theme(axis.title.x = element_blank()) +
  theme(text = element_text(size=15)) + theme(legend.title = element_blank())`

[image]

I would like to organize the bars from the bigger to the smaller bar. I had tried:

```
ggplot(New, aes(factor(reason), Mb, fill = category)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity" , position = "dodge") + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1") + theme(axis.title.x = element_blank()) +
  theme(text = element_text(size=15)) + theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c("All","Overlapped", "Absolute", "Reciprocal"))
```

However, I got the error.
Any ideas? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
library(ggplot2)
New$category <- with(New,reorder(category,Mb,function(x)-max(x)))

ggplot(New, aes(factor(reason), Mb, fill = category)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity" , position = "dodge") + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1") + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank()) + 
  theme(text = element_text(size=15)) + 
  theme(legend.title = element_blank())
```

[image]

Basically, we're reordering the factor levels based on the values in the `Mb` column.

Comment: Or the line for `reorder`ing could be shortened a bit to `New <- within(New, category <- reorder(category, -Mb))`